# Unit Test - Flow Variable to Apex Class to HttpRequest

Tags: apex, unit-test, visual-workflow, callout

For context, I am usually just a declarative Admin and can usually achieve whatever I need to on the platform using Flow, PB, or simple WFR. Very seldom do I have to 'resort' to Apex.

I have a Flow that constructs a JSON payload to be used in the body of an HttpRequest using Apex, and so at the end of the Flow I pass the payload to Apex. I managed to cobble together a Class that reads the payload, and performs the Callout thanks to some Google searching and some trial and error.

My class:

```
    public class flowHandlerCartRover {


    public class flowParameter{
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String getJSONData;
    }

     public class methodOutput{
        @InvocableVariable
        public String APIResult;
    } 


    @InvocableMethod(label='handleNewQuotes' description='Send New Quotes from Flow to Cart Rover')
    public static void handleNewQuotes(flowParameter[] flowParameters) {
        CartRover__c cr = CartRover__c.getInstance();
        String api_user = cr.API_User__c;
               api_user += ':'+ cr.API_Key__c;
        String endPoint = 'https://api.cartrover.com/v1/cart/orders/cartrover';


        System.debug('EndPoint:' + endPoint);

        // Instantiate a new http object
        Http h = new Http();

        // Instantiate a new HTTP request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+ EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueof(api_user)));

        System.debug('Input Request:' + flowParameters[0].getJSONData);
        req.setBody(flowParameters[0].getJSONData);

        // Send the request, and return a response
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
    }
}
```

I tried starting a Test class, but I keep getting `Invalid type: flowHandler.flowParameter` when attempting to assign a dummy payload value to the string `getJSONData`. The root class `flowHandlerCartRover` initiates just fine, but my issues come when calling the method. Here's what I have so far:

```
@isTest
private class flowHandlerCartRoverTest {  
    @isTest static void testCallout() {
        // Set mock callout class 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        //String getJSONData = '{"json" : "value"}';
        Test.startTest();
        flowHandlerCartRover flowHandler = new flowHandlerCartRover();
        flowHandler.flowParameter params = new flowHandler.flowParameter();
        params.getJSONData = '{"key":"value"}';

    }
}
```

At this point, I have no idea where to go in the test class. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  You need to construct a list of the custom apex type and pass to the invocable method

```
@isTest
private class flowHandlerCartRoverTest {  
  @isTest static void testCallout() {
   Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

   //  given an invocable class object
   flowHandlerCartRover flowHandler = new flowHandlerCartRover();
   // given input mocked as if coming from Flow
   flowHandlerCartRover.flowParameter param = new flowHandlerCartRover.flowParameter();
   param.getJsonData = '{"key":"value"}';

   flowHandlerCartRover.flowParameter[] params = new List<flowHandlerCartRover.flowParameter> {param};


   Test.startTest();
   // when invocable called
   flowHandler.handleNewQuotes(params);
   Test.stoptest();
 }
}
```

In addition, if you want to return values - something your invocable method isn't doing right now the signature needs to change to:

```
public static MethodOutput[] handleNewQuotes(flowParameter[] flowParameters) {..}
```

as an aside, I would rename the class as follows

```
CartRoverInvocable
```

the inner classes should be initial caps (this is where I got screwed up - methods and variables should be lowercase first letter; classes should be upper case first letter)

The method name should be action-oriented like `syncWithCartRover` (or something more appropriate)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I am still receiving the following: ``Invalid type: flowHandler.flowParameter`` + ``Variable does not exist: param`` + ``Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void handleNewQuotes(List<flowHandler.flowParameter>) from the type flowHandlerCartRover``

Comment: I corrected the test code - silly error on my part

Comment: So it turned out that I needed to initialize ``*.flowParameter`` as a list, then initialize the method in order to pass the param(s) to it. 

```// Build flowParameter 
        List<flowHandlerCartRover.flowParameter> params = new List<flowHandlerCartRover.flowParameter>();
        flowHandlerCartRover.flowParameter param = new flowHandlerCartRover.flowParameter();```

I also changed the method to a list, instead of an array ``public static void handleNewQuotes(List<flowParameter> flowParameters) {``